# Как использовать переменную, чтобы она перезаписывалась и значение не сбрасывалась на дефолт?

Tags: javascript

Есть div в которой находится результат

```
<div id="finance_reserve">0</div>
```

Есть кнопка по нажатию которой вызываю функцию

```
<input id='on_<?=$bloggers_neutral->id;?>' class='switcher-radio-on' type='radio' name='status_<?=$bloggers_neutral->id;?>' value='1' type="button" onclick="IntegrationCostProjctOn(<?=$bloggers_neutral->id;?>,<?=$data_platform->integration_cost?>);">
```

А вот JS код и функция в которой отрабатывает подсчёт денег

```
                                 <script type="text/javascript">

                                    // див где находятся бабки резерва
                                    var FinanceReserve = document.getElementById('finance_reserve');
                                    var FinanceReserve = 0;

                                    // Если у блогера переключили переключатель на "Согласовать"
                                    function IntegrationCostProjctOn(id_blogger, integration_cost)
                                    {
                                        var ElemIdBlogger = document.getElementById("on_"+id_blogger);
                                        
                                        // проверяем есть ли класс hook , чтобы не дублировать цену
                                        if(!ElemIdBlogger.classList.contains('hook'))
                                        {
                                            // добавляем класс hook
                                            ElemIdBlogger.classList.add("hook");

                                            FinanceReserve = Number(FinanceReserve) + Number(integration_cost);

                                            return FinanceReserve;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    console.log(FinanceReserve);

                                </script>
```

Мне нужно чтобы переменная **FinanceReserve** перезаписывалась и сохраняла в себе значение

Переменную **FinanceReserve** буду выводить в блок с id finance_reserve

И так же мне нужно использовать переменную **FinanceReserve** , в других функция

Например, такая же кнопка будет вызвать другую функцию но минусовать числа

Comment: Если требуется использовать какие-то данные и менять их (может и после перезагрузки страницы, то следует смотреть в сторону использования [Local Storage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage).

Comment: Не, такой метод не подходит мне. Так как есть сторона менеджера и сторона клиента и они должны оба видеть одно и тоже

Comment: @dmitrii_mv4 Ещё правее код нельзя было сделать, чтобы мы вообще не видели кода и догадывались что нужно скролить?

Comment: Что значит "чтобы переменная FinanceReserve перезаписывалась и сохраняла в себе значение"? У Вас и так переменная перезаписывается и сохраняет в себе значение в этом участке кода: FinanceReserve = Number(FinanceReserve) + Number(integration_cost);